# Напишите функцию, которая принимает вещественное число, и возвращает целое число округленное

Tags: java

Напишите функцию, которая принимает вещественное число, и возвращает целое число округленное к ближайшему целому.

Вот мой код:

```
public static int round(double x) {
        double number = x - ((int)x);
        double result = x - ((int)(x));
        if(number < 0.5){
            return ((int) x);
        }
        if (result < 0 && result >= -0.5){
            return ((int)(x));
        }
        if (number >= 0.5){
            return ((int) x) + 1;
        }
        else {
            return (int)x + (-1);
        }
    }
```

Округляет верно только положительные числа
отрицательные - нет

Подскажите пожалуйста где у меня ошибка может быть?

Comment: А банальный `return (int)(x + 0.5)` в Java не работает?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду без if вообще - работает. но только для положительных чисел.

Comment: А если число отрицательное - не округляет

Comment: Может кто-нибудь подскажет хотя бы мой алгоритм решения в том направлении или нет?

Comment: Вот действительно для положительных чисел код рабочий: public static int round(double x){
        int number = (int) (x + 0.5);
        return number;
    }

Comment: Выглядит странным и переусложненным. Например, number и result это одно и то же.

Comment: код сократила)) спасибо за совет, честно говоря код действительно получился длинный видимо я так рассуждала, но сейчас в тупике с отрицательным числом...

Comment: Должно быть примерно так: `if (x < 0) { return ... } else { return ... }`. Что написать вместо `...` уж можно придумать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int round(double x) {
    if(x>=0) return (int)(x+0.5);
    else return (int)(x-0.5);
}
```

Есть ещё класс java.lang.Math и в нём есть методы round() для округления, но -1.5 он округлит как -1

Comment: Огромное спасибо))) Всем... у меня плохая привычка раздувать из мухи слона. всего-то две строчки. а я напридумывала и запуталась ))

Comment: Это рабочий код